# Removing metal disc ring from chocolate mousse: which method should I use?

Tags: freezing, chocolate, refrigerator, mousse

I just managed to do a chocolate mousse with 5 layers (sponge, chocolate thin layer, nougat mousse, dark chocolate mousse, ganache). I added some "Agar Agar" to make it more firm and put them in the fridge to rest. Having used some INOX iron disc ring to give them shape (see photo) I wonder how I will be able to remove the ring leaving intact the mousse.

I thought I could use a little gas torch but I am not sure whether it is best to leave them in the fridge or to put them in the freezer so they get a bit more hard and less likely to get ruined when I extract the ring with the torch. In other words, I am worried that leaving them in the fridge they will be too fluffy to allow the disc ring to remove without damage.

What is the best way to remove them?

[image: Mousse]

Comment: Sliding metal rings off of a layered mousse is likely to smudge and smear the outside and blend your clean separation lines.  Consider using clear acetate cake wraps next time.  That way you can just unravel the wrap resulting in a cleaner finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal is to melt the outermost little bit and let the ring mold slide off.  Make sure they have had plenty of time to set up before unmolding.

The torch will work, although I would use a towel soaked in very very hot water, then squeezed dryish—just wrap it around the mold for ten or twenty seconds.   This maybe gentler than the torch, and less likely to go too far.

Edit:

Agar agar us *not* freeze stable, so you should not freeze your confections.

I imagine that eight hours is sufficiently long for a good chill, but I would go overnight if you can--a lot of labor goes into this sort of dish, so you don't want to loose the work.

Comment: Thank you. Good idea to use the hot towel. I was wondering if I should have added butter in the inner part inox silver disc. I decided not to add them as I thought that this would ruin the taste (some butter would have gone in the mousse, changing the flavour a bit). Could you add in your answer whether is best to freeze it or whether is not necessary? Would 10 hours of rest time in the fridge be enough? Thanks!

Comment: While I think that this would work. I think the torch would be more clean, I can imagine a chocolatey mess with a wet dish towel even if you wring it dry and you have to put your hands on a hot towel. Agar is fairly heat stable upwards of 80C so some quick torching should be just fine IMO.

Comment: The tea towel trick is very traditional... it shouldn't be messy if done with some care.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ the hot wipe trick worked PERFECTLY :), thumbs up for that. And thanks for the advice of not FREEZING the Agar Agar. I kept it in the fridge and the mousse seems to stay reasonably stable outside once out (I left it out for 2 hours so far and is still not loosing shape). Very happy for the result :) and VERY greatful for your precious advice.